# Knuth Morris Pratt Algorithm implementation in Perl

Tags: perl, knuth-morris-pratt

I am trying to implement the [Knuth Morris Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) in Perl. The following is my code and I referred Mastering Algorithms in Perl First Edition for the algorithm. When I run the code, it prints -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 as a result. Where am I going wrong?

Code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

#text
my $seq = "babacbadbbac";

#pattern
my $motif = "acabad";

#pass the text and pattern to knuth_morris_pratt subroutine
my @res = knuth_morris_pratt($seq, $motif);

#print the result
print "The resulting array is:";
print "@res";

#computation of the prefix subroutine
sub knuth_morris_pratt_next
{
   my($P) = @_; #pattern
   use integer;
   my ( $m, $i, $j ) = ( length $P, 0, -1 );
   my @next;
   for ($next[0] = -1; $i < $m; ) {
      # Note that this while() is skipped during the first for() pass.
      while ( $j > -1 && substr( $P, $i, 1 ) ne substr( $P, $j, 1 ) ) {
         $j = $next[$j];
      }
      $i++;
      $j++;
      $next[$i] = substr( $P, $j, 1 ) eq substr( $P, $i, 1 ) ? $next[$j] : $j;
   }
   return ( $m, @next ); # Length of pattern and prefix function.
}

#matcher subroutine
sub knuth_morris_pratt
{
   my ( $T, $P ) = @_; # Text and pattern.
   use integer;
   my ($m,@next) = knuth_morris_pratt_next( $P );
   my ( $n, $i, $j ) = ( length($T), 0, 0 );
   #my @next;
   my @val;
   my $k=0;
   while ( $i < $n ) 
   {
      while ( $j > -1 && substr( $P, $j, 1 ) ne substr( $T, $i, 1 ) ) 
      {
         $j = $next[$j];
      }
      $i++;
      $j++;
      if($j>=$m)
      {
          $val[$k]= $i - $j; # Match.
      }
      else
      {
          $val[$k]=-1; # Mismatch.
      }
      $k++;
   }
   return @val; 
}
```

Comment: have you tried to debug it using `perl -d your_script.pl`?

Comment: It says: Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.33
Editor support available.

Enter h or `h h' for help, or `man perldebug' for more help.

main::(q1.pl:3): my $seq="babacbadbbac";
  DB<1>

Comment: wonderful. Now debug it. `b Num` - set breakpoint. `r` - start program. `c` - continue. `p $var` - print variable value. `n` - execute next line. `s` - jump into procedure. `<enter>` - repeat previous command. `l` - print source code around

Comment: I dont understand, where do I type all this? I am sorry, I have never used it so getting confused

Comment: after starting `perl -d script`, you get into debugging session. `h` - get help, or use other commands as I listed above. This allows you to slowly execute your script line by line and see what's happening, or where it would get stuck

Comment: In `knuth_morris_pratt`, can you see that `@next` *never* holds any values, so `$j` is always set to `undef`? I don't think this is intentional.

Comment: @amon: you are probably right. but I think it much better to teach someone to fish, rather than giving them fish.

Comment: When I try to print variable value using p $seq, p $motif and p $res it is not showing me any value

Comment: @mvp I agree: my debugging strategy was running the code with `use warnings` → endless error messages of `$j` being undefined in `substr`, array subscript, and numeric comparision.

Comment: I edited my code to account for @next,                              my ($m,@next) = knuth_morris_pratt_next( $P );  Now it is printing -1 which must be the last value returned instead of all the values. So I have to see now how to call the subroutine such that all the values are returned

Comment: @VishalSinha are you sure you've already executed the statements that assign values to these vars? Use the `n` command to execute the next line. Then you should definitively get output.

Comment: Each time there is some value returned so I guess i should change $res to @res but I am worried how am I going to call the subroutine then?

Comment: I have tried to change my code so that it returns an array instead of a single number. Its not that I am not trying, I just need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the KMP algorithm returns an array with a -1 for each position of seq where the motif does not match and the index of a match for positions where it does.

For example, if you change the motif to "acbad" the array will  also contain a 3:

```
 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11   | index
"b  a  b  a  c  b  a  d  b  b  a   c"   | seq
         "a  c  b  a  d"                | motif
```

```
$> perl mq.pl "babacbadbbac" "acabad"
The resulting array is:
[-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] 

$> perl mq.pl "babacbadbbac" "acbad"
Match at index:3 
The resulting array is:
[-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [3] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] 


$> perl mq.pl "babacbadbbac" "ac" 
Match at index:3 
Match at index:10 
The resulting array is:
[-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [3] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [-1] [10]
```

---

**modified code**

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

my($seq,$motif) = @ARGV;

die "seq and motif required..." unless $seq and $motif;
die "motif should be <= seq ..." unless  length($motif) <= length($seq);

#pass the text and pattern to knuth_morris_pratt subroutine
my @res = knuth_morris_pratt($seq, $motif);

#print the result
print "The resulting array is:\n";
#print "@res";
print "[".join("] [",@res)."] \n";
#computation of the prefix subroutine
sub knuth_morris_pratt_next
{
   my($P) = @_; #pattern
   use integer;
   my ( $m, $i, $j ) = ( length $P, 0, -1 );
   my @next;
   for ($next[0] = -1; $i < $m; ) {
      # Note that this while() is skipped during the first for() pass.
      while ( $j > -1 && substr( $P, $i, 1 ) ne substr( $P, $j, 1 ) ) {
         $j = $next[$j];
      }
      $i++;
      $j++;
      $next[$i] = substr( $P, $j, 1 ) eq substr( $P, $i, 1 ) ? $next[$j] : $j;
   }
   return ( $m, @next ); # Length of pattern and prefix function.
}

#matcher subroutine
sub knuth_morris_pratt
{
   my ( $T, $P ) = @_; # Text and pattern.
   use integer;
   my ($m,@next) = knuth_morris_pratt_next( $P );
   my ( $n, $i, $j ) = ( length($T), 0, 0 );
   #my @next;
   my @val;
   my $k=0;
   while ( $i < $n ) 
   {
      while ( $j > -1 && substr( $P, $j, 1 ) ne substr( $T, $i, 1 ) ) 
      {
         $j = $next[$j];
      }
      $i++;
      $j++;
      if($j>=$m)
      {
          $val[$k]= $i - $j; # Match.
          print "Match at index:".$val[$k]." \n";
      }
      else
      {
          $val[$k]=-1; # Mismatch.
      }
      $k++;
   }
   return @val; 
}
```